# Unable to call function from external JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple HTML page which calls a JavaScript function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="css/myscript.js"></script>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body onload="javascript:hello()">
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my `hello()` function:

```
<script>
function hello() {
    alert("load new content");
    document.open();
    document.write("<h1>Changed content!</h1>");
    document.close();
}
</script>
```

When pasting the JavaScript block into the page directly, it works. However it's not able to find `hello()` if the JavaScript is contained within a dedicated file.

Using the Developer tools I can see that the JavaScript file is loaded successfully.

Comment: Are you sure `css/myscript.js` is the right path?

Comment: Your `<script>` isn't allowed directly in the `<html>` tag. It needs to be in either the `<head>` or the `<body>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have those script tags in your js file, get rid of them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. All answers were correct. I will mark it as correct as this was the first reply.

Answer (score 1):

2 issues, during parsing of your script, document is already open. If you open again, everything will be deleted so get rid of it(write is already a call to open). Second, make sure you do not add the script after the load event, so that function hello is really defined. Here I am adding it right within body (or you can use defer if you want.) [Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/jk8anfu6/1/)

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body onload="hello();">
</body>



 function hello() {
      alert("load new content");
      //document.open();
      document.write("<h1>Changed content!</h1>");
      document.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The contents of `myscript.js` should just be:

```
function hello() {
  alert("load new content");
  document.open();
  document.write("<h1>Changed content!</h1>");
  document.close();
}
```

You would include the `<script>` tag only if your JavaScript were inside your HTML file; the `<script>` is what tells the browser, "Hey, we're not interpreting HTML anymore. This is JavaScript."

Also, as Colin pointed out in the comments, `myscript.js` probably doesn't belong in your `css` folder. A common name for the folder that contains all your website's JavaScript files is `js`.